# Error when importing Pandas from python canopy

Tags: python, enthought, statsmodels

I have installed Python Canopy 2.7 and have made it the default. When I start python I see the version from "Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.6 | 64-bit |"

I can import pandas and numpy... but when I try to import statsmodels.api I get this error

```
ImportError: No module named statsmodels
```

I have checked the Enthought website and in theory statsmodels would be inclueded in the express distribution.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Thanks! Just realized I have to install the required packages from the package manager... thought they would come already installed... which makes me wonder how I could import pandas... as it was not installed as well...

Comment: OK, thanks!! Do you want to make it an answer so I can check as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enthought Canopy comes bundled with a package manager. Use that package manager to install the module you require.

You are able to import `pandas` and `numpy`, since the installation comes bundled with these modules along with `matplotlib` etc.